# perfect separation after adding interaction term

Tags: interaction, logit

I am using `glm` to estimate a model (dependent is dummy). I have two continuous variables that I want to test their interaction. As soon as I add the interaction term I get perfect separation error. (sample size is: 107348)
Any suggestions?

Here is what I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

**I need to add that, both variables have very wide ranges. When I use log transform of those variables I do not get perfect separation issue anymore.**

Comment: What is your sample size; how many degrees of freedom does that interaction cost?

Comment: Also, are you using any sample weights?

Comment: I struggle to see how you can get perfect separation with continuous predictors. What one is more likely to have is quasi-separation. Additionally, this error need not relate to separation problems. The second warning simply comes down to extreme logits which can arise for a variety of reasons.

Comment: The sample size is: 107,348. I have both factor (categorical) and continuous predictor, but this issue happens when I add the interaction of two continuous variables.

Comment: Also this happens when I add one additional continuous variable. I tried a model with just that one variable and I get the same error (fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred) again.

Comment: Also when I use log of that variable, I don't get perfect separation issue anymore!

Comment: Give an example